# Task runs when I select "Run" but get logon failure on a scheduled start

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I have created a task in Task Scheduler which will run when I click the "Run" command, but not when scheduled. It is a C# application which I want the Task Scheduler to run on system start up.

I have configured it to "Run whether user is logged on or not" and have set a user account. I am sure that this account has the correct password because when I save changes from Properties I am prompted for credentials and I enter the same user name and password.

If I right click on the task and select Run then the task starts successfully.

However, on system start up it does not start. When I look in the event log I can see that it attempts to start but got the error 2147943726. The text says:

> Task Scheduler failed to log on "my task name". Failure occurred  in "LogonUserExEx".User Action: Ensure the credentials for the task are correctly specified.

The credentials are correctly entered.

I have looked at some other questions regarding this but they did not seem to solve the issue. I have ensured that the logged on user has Full Control of the executable it is trying to run.

I have not checked the "Do not store password" box because the task will need to access more than local resources (it may have to send an email)

Just to emphasis if I click the "Run" action it starts and runs successfully, it is just on scheduled start it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was happening here.

There was already another scheduled task configured to start at system start up that used the same credentials. This task was starting successfully but my, very similar task was failing.

When I disabled the first task and restarted the system then my task started successfully. I concluded that Task Scheduler was not happy to start two tasks with the same credentials. I fixed this by editing the batch file for the other task so that it launches its own task and then starts my executable also.